# Can not execute Sonar: Fail to decorate

Tags: maven-plugin, sonarqube

I installed a sonar server on my own pc (Windows XP), and I deployed sonar on Tomcat with a MySQL database.
I successfully analysed an old project. But with my current project, I get this exception when trying to execute `mvn sonar:sonar`:

EDIT:

```
[INFO] [14:39:37.254] Sensor CoberturaSensor done: 218 ms
[INFO] [14:39:37.254] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [14:39:41.426] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 4172 ms
[INFO] [14:39:41.848] Execute decorators...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:53.354s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 15 14:39:43 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/138M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (d
efault-cli) on project XXX: Can not execute Sonar: Fail to decorate 'com.myPackage
.myClass': 793 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project XXX: Can
not execute Sonar
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar

        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)

        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'com.myPackage.myClass
'
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(Decorators
Executor.java:84)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(Decorators
Executor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(Decorators
Executor.java:63)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(Decorators
Executor.java:63)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.
java:55)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:94)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:14
3)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:115)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:105)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.jav
a:109)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:59)
        at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:143)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:113)

        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 793
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.tracking.HashedSequenceComparator.
equals(HashedSequenceComparator.java:34)
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.ViolationTrackingBlocksRecognizer.
computeLengthOfMaximalBlock(ViolationTrackingBlocksRecognizer.java:48)
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.ViolationTrackingDecorator.mapViol
ations(ViolationTrackingDecorator.java:130)
        at org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.ViolationTrackingDecorator.decorat
e(ViolationTrackingDecorator.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(Decorators
Executor.java:79)
        ... 39 more
```

I don't understand where the problem comes from. Please anyone have an answer? Can it come from my POM configuration?

PS: the command lines `mvn clean install` and `mvn site` work correctly...

Comment: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Do this and post it here please.

Comment: @oers, I edited the stack trace with the -e switch.

Comment: I deleted a previous version of my projet on sonar and now it works find. Thank you for mutting me on the way. But I still do not understand the problem.

Comment: it is a bug :) you don't have to "understand" it ;) Take a look at Fabrices answer and update sonar to 3.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're facing a bug of Sonar 3.0 (=> http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3442). We have release Sonar 3.0.1 (see http://www.sonarsource.org/downloads/) that fixes this issue.

Comment: You are right, it was the same bug. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Do you have also an idea on how "replay the past" with sonar and svn ?

Comment: You can use the property "sonar.projectDate" (see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Advanced+parameters).